# Should "WHEN" be placed before the 1st part in this sentence? | "I was moving fast down a steep hill, when I took a tumble."

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, clauses

**I was moving fast down a steep hill heading towards the village of Gifford for breakfast when I took a tumble.** [BBC -My brain cancer diagnosis was a total shock](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-67925522)

When you read the sentence, you understand that the main thing or main clause is **"to take a tumble"**, not **"to move fast"**. And **"moving fast"** was interrupted by **"a fall"**.

What was insterrupted is not **"my fall"**, but **"my going down"**. So, the action which was interrupted should have the **"WHEN/WHILE"**. Or this is at least what we were taught at school.

For instance:

**"When I was cleaning the window, somebody knocked the door."**

or

**"When I was listening the music, the phone rang."**

As you see, in both sentences, the interrupted action (LISTEN/CLEAN) starts with **"WHEN/WHILE"**, not the interrupting action(KNOCK/RING).

But, in our sentence, it is the opposite. The interrupted action doesn't start with **"WHEN"**, which does not sit well in my mind (maybe because of my native language.) Shouldn't it have been one of the either ways:

**WHEN/WHILE I was moving fast down .........., I took a tumble.**

or

**"I was moving fast down....., and suddenly I took a tumble."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clause with the simple past "when I took a tumble" refers to a fall, something that happened in an instant in time.  The clause with the continuous verb, "I was  moving fast down a steep hill...", refers to an action-in-progress, something which happened over a span in time.

The subordinate clause with the simple past can come *before or after* the independent clause.

If the subordinate clause introduces the sentence it presents the instant event without context, which is delayed.  If the clause with the continuous introduces the sentence, it "sets the stage" for the instant event. The choice is rhetorical, not grammatical.

P.S. The word **when** can appear in either clause, the clause whose action is interrupted or the clause whose action interrupts, and either clause can introduce the sentence:

> I was snowboarding when I fell.
>
> When I was snowboarding, I fell.
>
> When I fell, I was snowboarding.
>
> I fell when I was snowboarding.

When the word **when** appears in the clause with the ongoing action ("when I was snowboarding") it is understood to mean "while", i.e. *during* the ongoing act; when the word **when** appears in the clause with the incident action ("when I fell") it refers to the time, i.e. the moment, of the incident action.

Comment: You meant **independent** clause and **dependent** clause?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will edit.  Distracted :-)

Comment: -1, sorry: The OP isn't asking about the order of the two clauses, (s)he's asking about which clause should be the subordinate clause. Apparently (s)he was taught that we say "when [action in progress], [instant event]" rather than "[action in progress] when [instant event]".

Comment: @ruakh: Added a P.S.

Comment: @TimR, thanks for the answer. This is simply a better explanation -on this issue- than the grammer books we studied at school.